Android Appium long press not working on 2.5.1
On my local appium that runs 2.0.1 this works:
  WebElement element = assertElement(new AppiumBy.ByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().resourceId(\"" + resourceId + "\")"));
        //logic to long press on my to do
        TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
        action.longPress(ElementOption.element(element)).release().perform();

However on my remote appium that runs from jenkins, I havef 2.5.1 and there I get a:
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource
Build info: version: '4.9.1', revision: 'eb2032df7f'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '14.0', java.version: '20.0.2'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [34caf98b-9993-44bb-8b5b-06f8db975aec, performTouchAction {actions=[{action=longPress, options={duration=2000, element=00000000-0000-0144-0000-0110000000af}}, {action=release, options={}}]}]
Capabilities {appium:app: /Users/testlaptopmac/Downlo..., appium:appPackage: com.xelion8.android.debug, appium:applicationName: xcover5, appium:autoGrantPermissions: true, appium:automationName: UiAutomator2, appium:databaseEnabled: false, appium:desired: {app: /Users/testlaptopmac/Downlo..., applicationName: xcover5, autoGrantPermissions: true, automationName: UiAutomator2, deviceName: xcover5, platformName: ANDROID, udid: R58T70RWNTZ}, appium:deviceApiLevel: 33, appium:deviceManufacturer: samsung, appium:deviceModel: SM-G525F, appium:deviceName: R58T70RWNTZ, appium:deviceScreenDensity: 340, appium:deviceScreenSize: 720x1480, appium:deviceUDID: R58T70RWNTZ, appium:javascriptEnabled: true, appium:locationContextEnabled: false, appium:networkConnectionEnabled: true, appium:pixelRatio: 2.125, appium:platformVersion: 13, appium:statBarHeight: 51, appium:takesScreenshot: true, appium:udid: R58T70RWNTZ, appium:viewportRect: {height: 1429, left: 0, top: 51, width: 720}, appium:warnings: {}, appium:webStorageEnabled: false, platformName: ANDROID, se:bidiEnabled: false, se:cdpEnabled: false}
Session ID: 34caf98b-9993-44bb-8b5b-06f8db975aec

I tried checking the docs but I don't undestand what changed, or with what to replace, please help
This is my setup:
       UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options().setApp(androidInfo.apkUrl())
                                                           .setAutoGrantPermissions(androidInfo.autoGrantPermissions())
                                                           .setDeviceName(androidInfo.device());

    driver = new AndroidDriver(testGridInfo.url(), options);

EDIT:
I managed to do the "click" like this: but I need to "long press"
any ideas?
 int x = element.getLocation().getX() + (size.width / 2);
        int y = element.getLocation().getY() + (size.height / 2);
        PointerInput finger = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH, "finger");
        Sequence tap = new Sequence(finger, 1);
        tap.addAction(finger.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(0), PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), x, y));
        tap.addAction(finger.createPointerDown(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));
        waitForTime(2000); //simulate long press
        tap.addAction(finger.createPointerUp(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));
        driver.perform(Arrays.asList(tap));


I managed like this:
WebElement element = assertElement(new AppiumBy.ByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().resourceId(\"" + resourceId + "\")"));
        //logic to long press on my to do
        Dimension size = element.getSize();
        int x = element.getLocation().getX() + (size.width / 2);
        int y = element.getLocation().getY() + (size.height / 2);
        PointerInput finger = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH, "finger");
        Sequence tap = new Sequence(finger, 1);
        tap.addAction(finger.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(0), PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), x, y));
        tap.addAction(finger.createPointerDown(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));
        tap.addAction(new Pause(finger, Duration.ofMillis(2000)));
        tap.addAction(finger.createPointerUp(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));
        driver.perform(Arrays.asList(tap));

